# Windowsless application, threads and Invoke()

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading

Let's suppose I have windowsless application: only NotifyIcon is presented. So I've created the only NotifyIcon that I need. But when I had a `Form1` class I could use `form1.Invoke(action)` to perform actions from another thread. And what should I do now?

**UPD**: this is an answer: we should Invoke() a menu itself

```
if (mnuTrayMenu.InvokeRequired)
  mnuTrayMenu.Invoke(action);
else
  action();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question, I've solved this with:

```
    if (mnuTrayMenu.InvokeRequired)
        mnuTrayMenu.Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
```